# Flag a review inappropriate through api call

Tags: google-places-api

I am using google places api to pull in all the google reviews into my site. I want to add a button for flagging inappropriate reviews, but is this possible through to make a call along with the places id? I don't see any ids associated with the reviews when I get the response from google api.

Comment: did you found anything about this? ty